# Hibernate time with joda one hour previous error

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

I have an `Hibernate class` and for a time column in `MySqlDb` I'm using in Java

```
 @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalTimeAsTime")
 @Column(name = "hour", length = 8)
 public LocalTime getHour() {
    return this.hour;
}
```

So my problem is if I have in DB 07:20:33
when I get the value I have 06:20:33

Comment: What timezone is one the Java server and DB server?

Comment: They Are on the same machine

Comment: SOlved: now I USE org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalTimeAsString